# JSONP parse error from NON-JSON service

Tags: jquery, ajax

`enter code here`There is a third party web service (soap) that returns the value(s) from a search that is in thier website.  I can call this service using a plain old URL that includes the parameters of the search.  ex. city, state, or zip.  This service returns a well formatted XML string.

The problem is...   using Javascript, i can call the service/url without a problem.

But the callback is failing.   The message that is displayed indicates a parse error.

Using firefox and firebug, i can see the results are being returned correctly, just in plain old XML.

It appears the ajax callback is trying to parse the results, but it is failing.

This third party is on a completly different web site, so cross site scripting rules do apply.

So the question(s) are...

1) Is there a way to NOT perform the parsing, and just get the results?
2) Are there any additional parameters that i can tweak that will allow me to see and work the result set?

Here is the code i am using...

```
  function LoadMenu() {
    varType = "GET";
    varUrl = "https://www.xxxx.com/soap/352mg/xml.php?callback=?";
    varData = { zip: 68105 };
    varContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
    varDataType = "jsonp";
    varProcessData = false;
    $.ajax({
      crossdomain: true,
      type: varType, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
      url: varUrl, // Location of the service
      data: varData, //Data sent to server
      contentType: varContentType, // content type sent to server
      dataType: varDataType, //Expected data format from server
      processdata: false, // varProcessData, //True or False
      success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
        serviceSucceeded(msg);
      },
      error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

JSONP is a hacky solution to cross domain restrictions, it includes a new script tag in the html so the src is automatically parsed by the browser. You cannot disable it.

If you need to fetch XML and they don't provide JSONP or some kind of Cross Domain Request (like CORS) then you will need to setup a proxy. By setting up a proxy you can fetch the data with some other means (like PHP) and then reroute it to whatever page on your domain might need it.